# how can I suppress some output from the Python Library TextBlob sentiment.polarity

Tags: python, output, textblob, suppress

I am using Python to assign labels to results returned from TextBlob.
My very basic code looks like this:

```
from textblob import TextBlob

def sentLabel(blob):
    label = blob.sentiment.polarity 

    if(label == 0.0):
        print('Neutral')
    elif(label > 0.0):
        print('Positive')
    else:
        print('Negative')

    Feedback1 = "The food in the canteen was awesome"
    Feedback2 = "The food in the canteen was awful"
    Feedback3 = "The canteen has food"


    b1 = TextBlob(Feedback1)
    b2 = TextBlob(Feedback2)
    b3 = TextBlob(Feedback3)

    print(b1.sentiment_assessments)
    print(sentLabel(b1))
    print(b2.sentiment_assessments)
    print(sentLabel(b2))
    print(b3.sentiment_assessments)
    print(sentLabel(b3))
```

This prints out the sentiment correctly but it also prints out "None" as shown below:

```
Sentiment(polarity=1.0, subjectivity=1.0, assessments=[(['awesome'], 1.0, 1.0, None)])

Positive

None

...
```

Is there any way to suppress "None" from being printed?

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `sentLabel` return `None`. Hence when you use `print(sentLabel(b1))`, it prints `None`.

This should work for you.

```
from textblob import TextBlob

def sentLabel(blob):
    label = blob.sentiment.polarity 

    if(label == 0.0):
        print('Neutral')
    elif(label > 0.0):
        print('Positive')
    else:
        print('Negative')

    Feedback1 = "The food in the canteen was awesome"
    Feedback2 = "The food in the canteen was awful"
    Feedback3 = "The canteen has food"


    b1 = TextBlob(Feedback1)
    b2 = TextBlob(Feedback2)
    b3 = TextBlob(Feedback3)

    print(b1.sentiment_assessments)
    sentLabel(b1)
    print(b2.sentiment_assessments)
    sentLabel(b2)
    print(b3.sentiment_assessments)
    sentLabel(b3)
```

Comment: Thanks Anurag, that works. I also came across this article which explained to a newbie like me why none was being returned: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-return-none-from-Python-function